# Without authenticating DB I can access the data in mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb

I have added authentication by following steps:

1. Created the user administrator.

   *use admin
   db.createUser(
   {
   user: "superAdmin",
   pwd: "admin123",
   roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
   })*
2. Re-start the MongoDB instance with access control
3. Check below lines in mongodb.conf file

   *security:
     authorization: enabled*
4. Restarted mongodb
5. Connectd to database instance with superAdmin access

   *mongo --port 27017 -u "superAdmin" -p "admin123" --authenticationDatabase 
   "admin"*
6. Created user access (readWrite) for a specific database

   *$ mongo --port 27017 -u "superAdmin" -p "admin123" --authenticationDatabase 
   "admin"
   $ use myAppDb
   $ db.createUser(
     {
      user: "myAppDbUser",
      pwd: "myApp123",
      roles: [ "readWrite"]
     })*

Then I have reopened the mongo shell and try to access DB by following steps:

1. use myAppDb
2. show collections

I can see all my collections without authenticating it.

I want that without authenticating nobody can see my DB.

I am using version 3.6 of mongoDB.

Thanks in advance :)